# 65W TDP CPU in a Socket with a 95W TDP CPU

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I have a PC which currently has a Pentium D 945 (http://www.cpu-upgrade.com/CPUs/Intel/Pentium_D/945.html) Which has a TDP of 95W, and I would like to upgrade to a Core 2 Duo E4400 (http://www.cpu-upgrade.com/CPUs/Intel/Core_2_Duo/E4400.html) Which has a a TDP of 65W.

Can I use the Core 2 Duo in that PC without any errors? The PC has Socket 775 and all these CPUs fit in that socket.

Comment: While they're the same socket, its worth checking if your *motherboard* supports the core 2. Chipset support will be more of an issue than TDP here

Comment: On CPU upgrade, the Core 2 E4400 is shown as supported with the i945G chipset as well as the Pentium which is currently has. I will search around some more. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no.

Yes: You can use a CPU with a less TPD than the maximum rated for that socket.

Think about it like driving either a car with a maximum speed of 95kmph or a maximum speed of 65 kmph on a road which has been declared safe up to 95 kmph.

And no: You can not just any other CPU, even if it has equal or less power usage. (Roughly translated: TPD is how much power is used on average and thus how much heat must be dissipated).

In order for that to work additional demands must be met. E.g.

1. The BIOS in your computer must recognise the new CPU (not always the case).
2. The sockets must be identical (in your case both are socket 775).
3. The voltages and communication on these pins must be compatible. (not sure here: The core2 is an Alendale. The older Pentium D 945 is a Presler core).

As for the voltages: According to [http://ark.intel.com/](http://ark.intel.com/compare/29753,27520) your corw2 only expects between 
0.8500V and 1.5V volts, while your Pentium-D expects between 1.2 and 1.3375 volt. Can you motherboard handle that? If not it will either not work or not work stable.

(and given that we are crossing from an older generation to a newer CPU generation even if it matches that might not be enough).

Having written all that:

- These kind of questions are rather specific. They are unlikely to help many people and thus (as formulated) are a bad question for this site.
- There are multiple (as yet unclosed) answers on this site. Try the search function.
- Without more information there is (and can be) no full answer.
- Both of these CPUs are ancient: While I enjoy toying with those kind of things, I do not consider them an economic upgrade at all. Only consider this if you like toying with hardware and if the system is non-critical.